# Azure CLI authentication timed out

Tags: c#, .net-7.0, xunit.net, c#-11.0, dotnet-test

I keep getting the message 'Azure CLI authentication timed out' when running Xunit tests using dotnet test. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the synchronous version of the Azure CLI authentication. In my case I was using this code:

```
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(uri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
var secret = client.GetSecretAsync(key).Result;
```

I resolved the issue by changing the second line to this:

```
var secret = client.GetSecret(key);
```